# how to find how long my ssh connection is being active

Tags: linux, bash

Doing some platform automation and planning to devise some logic around how long a user ssh session is being active. is there a way to find?

Comment: What is this `ssh` session doing?  Executing a shell and waiting for user input most of the time?  Executing some program?  What do you want happening based on time elapsed?  Do you have some code you have tried to write but fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the output of "last", maybe it would be sufficient?

```
server ~ $ last
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Fri Dec 11 10:35   still logged in
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Thu Dec 10 11:12 - 11:22  (00:09)
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Thu Dec 10 09:19 - 11:09  (01:50)
```

Comment: Hello mate, i have done it now, sorry didnt know how to

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `ps` command?

```
[STEP 101] # ps -C sshd o user,pid,comm,lstart
USER        PID COMMAND                          STARTED
root        603 sshd            Thu Mar  9 11:48:29 2017
root      15147 sshd            Mon Mar 13 10:19:21 2017
root      16193 sshd            Mon Mar 13 10:19:43 2017
root      19858 sshd            Mon Mar 13 10:23:06 2017
pynexj    19860 sshd            Mon Mar 13 10:23:06 2017
root      21444 sshd            Mon Mar 13 15:11:58 2017
root      22526 sshd            Mon Mar 13 17:24:35 2017
root      70528 sshd            Wed Apr 12 17:14:12 2017
[STEP 102] #
```